# WordPress | Transient the default WP_Query results

Tags: wordpress, caching, transient

I have create a web site with a lot of traffic, and I have use the WordPress transients in order to "cache" the requested data. Until here all are fine with my custom made queries and usage of WP_Query.

The question that I have, is how can I "cache" the data return by the WordPress "Loop" in categories?

In categories theme file I am using the default loop code, in order to print the data, but I don't have access on the WP_Query results for this theme file.

So, Is there a way to cache the data provided by the WordPress in Categories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice from the [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache#Persistent_Caching) is to install a Persistent caching plugin

Comment: I know that, but this is not what I need this time. I only need to cache the data as it is.

Comment: Ok, the link I posted should still help though: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache
`$result = wp_cache_get( 'my_result' );

if ( false === $result ) {

 $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

 wp_cache_set( 'my_result', $result );

} 

// Do something with $result;`